# How to insert symbols into MySQL database?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, database

I created a page that inserts some data into MySQL database using PHP and jQuery. It's working great but the problem is when I try to insert symbols, for example:

```
 :) :( :P =D :o ;) :v >:( :/ :'( ^_^ 8) B| <3 3:) O:) -_- o.O >:o :3 (y)
```

I get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax

Code (that inserts the data into the database)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#insert").click(function(){
      var meesg=$("#reply").val();
      clear();
      $.post('full.php', {messagge: meesg, from: 'cevin', to: 'calvin'},
          function(data){
              $("#message").html(data);
              $("#message").hide();
              $("#message").fadeIn(200);
          });
      return false;
    });
    function clear() {
      $("#myre:input").each(function() {
          $(this).val('');
      });
    }
});
</script>
<a id="insert" title="Insert Data" href="#">Push into mysql</a>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("datab");
$to=$_POST['to'];
$from=$_POST['from'];
$msg=$_POST['msgg'];
if(empty($msg)){
    exit();
}
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `thetable`(`to`,`from`,`message`) VALUES ('$to','$from','$msg')");
mysql_real_escape_string($query);
if($query){
    echo "Inserted successfully!";
}
else{ 
    echo "An error occurred!"; 
}
?>
```

How can I solve this problem of inserting symbols into the database?

Comment: [how-to-prevent-sql-injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) >> Recomended.

Comment: [The great Escapism](http://kunststube.net/escapism)

Comment: I'm so glad mysql_* got removed from PHP 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape **parameters**, NOT the whole query (especially you made it after execution, which simply makes no sense at all as it is simply far too late). So this is wrong:

```
# this is wrong!
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `thetable`(`to`,`from`,`message`) VALUES ('$to','$from','$msg')");
mysql_real_escape_string($query);
```

This is better (but still, switch to PDO or at least use `mysqli_`):

```
# this is right
$q = sprintf("INSERT INTO `thetable`(`to`,`from`,`message`) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')",
      mysql_real_escape_string($to),
      mysql_real_escape_string($from),
      mysql_real_escape_string($msg));
$query=mysql_query($q);
```

Comment: do you mean like this `mysql_real_escape_string($msg);` for example

Comment: A better answer would advise the OP to not use the mysql_* functions any more because they're no longer supported, horribly out of date, deprecated in all supported versions of PHP 5 and completely removed in PHP 7

Comment: I believe `but still, switch to PDO or at least use mysqli_` address your complain nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the fact you should really use PDO or MySQLi you can't escape the whole query you must escape the parameters:

```
$to = mysql_real_escape_string($to);
$from = mysql_real_escape_string($from);
$msg = mysql_real_esacpe_string($msg);
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `thetable`(`to`,`from`,`message`) VALUES ('$to','$from','$msg')");
```

Answer (score 0):

U have to escape most symbols security reasons... and while u are at it u can use some sort of sanitation for your SQL input. My advice is to learn to prepare statements and etc. More info can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

If you don't protect the input to sql you are gonna have some bad time when somebody decides to play a prank on you or destroy your database all together.

PS: Preparing statements is better than escaping strings.

Comment: Great,I was also searching for that! Thank you!!